# Adding the sub menu item to send to item in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, custom-actions

How can we add an additional entry to "Send To" menu option in document libraries. What is the GroupID and Location for adding item to the sub menu. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  this  link  help  you.

http://angler.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/sharepoint-2010-document-center-send-to-connection-setup-walkthrough/

Comment: Please do not only provide links as answer, add an abstract about the part that can help the OP out. The link may get obsolete, so your answer should be helpful on its own.